# Is an ellipsoid defined as a quadric always symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#As_quadric), one can read that points $\mathbf{x}\in{\rm I\!R}^3$ of an ellipsoid of center $\mathbf{v}\in {\rm I\!R}^3$ are solution of the equation
$$
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v})^T A (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v}) = 1
$$
where $A$ is a positive definite matrix.

**Is the matrix $A$ also symmetric ?** I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms) that any matrix $Q$ of a quadratic form $x^T Q x$ can be made symmetric using $\frac{1}{2}(Q+Q^T)$ instead.

**What happen if the matrix $A$ is not positive definite ?** If one of its eigenvalues is null or negative, what is the shape described by such equation? I feel like a cone or a cylinder can be represented.

**Does it means that there exist a matrix $V$ such that $A=V^T V$ ?** I read this statement [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/63022). In this case, what are the properties of $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when someone says "positive definite", they are using the definition of "positive definite" which implies "symmetric". I.e. positive definite matrices are usually symmetric *by definition*.

If one of the eigenvalues is null, you get a degenerate conic section. If one of the eigenvalues is negative, you get a conic section with negative curvature, analogous to a hyperbola, i.e. hyperboloids in $\mathbb{R}^3$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space

Yes, it is true that every positive definite matrix has a square root, i.e. a matrix $V$ such that $V^\top V = A$, one way to find $V$ is to do a [Cholesky factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), another way is to take the eigenvalue decomposition of $A = U D U^\top$. All of the entries of $D$ are positive, so one can define the entrywise square root, $\sqrt{D}$, so then $A = (U \sqrt{D}) (\sqrt{D} U^\top) = (U^\top \sqrt{D})^\top (U^\top \sqrt{D})$, so define $V = \sqrt{D} U^\top$. (Note also that the singular value decomposition and eigenvalue decomposition coincide for a positive definite matrix, so one could also get the matrix square root using the SVD.)

Comment: In case of null or negative eigenvalue, what is the meaning of the "center" $\mathbf{v}$?

Comment: The centering is just a change of variables -- it corresponds to a translation/rigid motion which doesn't affect the shape of the quadratic form. E.g. in R^2 if all eigenvalues are positive, then if v=(1,1) the quadratic form corresponds to an ellipse centered at (1,1), but if v=(0,0) then the ellipse is centered at the origin  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)  I feel like I maybe don't understand the question though since the signs of the eigenvalues would not affect the geometry specified by the center as well as vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Any quadric surface, not just an ellipsoid, can be written 
$$\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&h&g&s\\h&b&f&p\\g&f&c&q\\s&p&q&r\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{bmatrix}=[0].$$